# How to return different variations of a string according to condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

I'd like to return different strings according to the conditions. 
I have a form of 3 questions and every question has 4 options to select from (radio) and every option has a value.. It looks like this:

```
Question                 Possible Answers          Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
                              1-25                   0
                              26-40                  5
question 1                    41-60                  8
                              60+                    10
-----------------------------------------------------------
                              1-25                   0
                              26-40                  5
question 2                    41-60                  10
                              60+                    10
-----------------------------------------------------------
                              1-25                   0
                              26-40                  5
question 3                    41-60                  10
                              60+                    15
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the values for every question and now I want to return a custom string IF the sum of the values is greater than 25. In the string I want to display if a question's value is greater or equal to 10.

For example: the user chose option 2 for question 1 (value = 5), option 3 for question 2 (value = 10), and option 4 for question 3 (value = 15)

my string would be: The highest values are in question 2 and question 3.

here is what I experimented with:

```
if (total_Value > 25) {
  switch (true) {
    case (question1_Value >= 10 && question2_Value >= 10 && question3_Value < 10)
      return "Highest values are in question1 and question2";
    case (question1_Value >= 10 && question2_Value < 10 && question3_Value >= 10):
      return "Highest values are in question1 and question3";
    }
}
```

and so on.. I was basically checking every possibility and modified the return accordingly but its not the best especially if I have 5 questions for example.

I was hoping to do this without a huge switch statement or if statements. Please help. I hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Are you always listing two questions with the highest values? What about if you have 3 questions with the same score? Or if 2 and 3 are tied?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data format do you have? Are questions arrays, objects, a combination? What does it look like?

Comment: I was experimenting with the switch statement but it got super long so I thought there must be an easier way to do this... Its basically about what to include in the return string and what not. I edited the post with my code

Comment: Anytime you end up with numbered variables like `var1, var2, var3` it usually means you should be using an array/list instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical mistake when people first start out to learn programming. You try to do too much with the logic you have and end up with a thousand **if/else/else if**, **switch statements**, **while loops**, and **for loops**. You especially see this with newer people trying to implement the classic tic-tac-toe game, but this is another example.

The problem isn't what you're trying to do, it's how you're managing your data.

Your values for each question should **not** be stored in individual variables, at least while you're trying to calculate the highest values. The data relates to each other. We need to show that with code. The best way to do this is to either store the information in an array or, alternatively, an object.

You also need to consider what it is you're looking for. You want an output that dictates what questions(presumably two) have the highest values. This is all well and good, but that means we somehow need to relay what question goes with what value. We can either determine this through the **order of parameters**(using an array) or an **explicit label**(using an object) stored with your data that tells your program what question it's linked to, or combine them as in the below.

We use `Array.prototype.reduce` to get the highest score. We allow an exclusion parameter that will ignore a singular value. When we call the function with this exclusion parameter we can get the second highest value.

We return a question number based on its index in the array(+1, since indices start at 0) and a value. These are combined as properties on the returned object. This makes it easy to get both the highest, and second highest values, and display them in console or on screen.

```js
var q1 = 10,
  q2 = 10,
  q3 = 50,
  value_arr = [q1, q2, q3],
  max = highest(value_arr),
  max2 = highest(value_arr, max.value);

console.log("question " + max.question + " and question " + max2.question + " are the highest.");

function highest(value_array, exclude = null) {
  return value_array.reduce(function(max, v, currentIndex) {
    if (v > max.value && v != exclude) {
      max.value = v;
      max.question = currentIndex + 1
    }
    return max;
  }, {
    question: 0,
    value: 0
  });
};
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation! I'll try it out for sure :)